# Distributed Tensorflow: ps/workers hosts on aws ?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using distributed Tensorflow on aws using gpus. When I train the model on my local machine, I indicate ps_host/workers_host as something like 'localhost:2225'.  What are the ps/workers host I need to use in case of aws?

Answer (score 2):

here's a good github project showing how to use Distributed TensorFlow on AWS with Kubernetes or the new AWS SageMaker:  https://github.com/pipelineai/pipeline

at minimum, you should be using the TensorFlow Estimator API.  there are lots of hidden, not-so-well-documented tricks to Distributed TensorFlow.

some of the better examples live here:  https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census

Answer (score 0):

When a distributed TF code is run on the cluster, other nodes could be accessed through "`private ip: port number`".

But the problem with AWS is that the other nodes can not be easily launched and it needs extra configuration.